# Inserting CSV Data Into Azure SQL DB After Already Creating a Function To Read CSV Data?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Function (Http Trigger) that reads data from a CSV file via HttpRequestMessage. To show you my reader code, I have included it in this post.

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log) {
try
        {
            // This will read the CSV Data
            var multipart = await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
            // This gets CSV names
            foreach (var content in multipart.Contents)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(await content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        log.Info(line);
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

I am able to test by uploading my CSV file in postman and hitting the endpoint to get a response that includes all data from the CSV. I created an Azure SQL Database that also reflects all table relationships. I now would like to write the data that is read from this function into the corresponding tables. I don't know if it's possible to do in the same Azure Function.

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adapting the following code to you function:

```
    var cnnString  = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString;

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
    {
        connection.Open();


        // You read your CSV
        var rLog = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<LogRequest>();
        connection.Execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[LogRequest] ([Log]) VALUES (@Log)", rLog);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Alberto. I don't currently want to open a connection like this in my project, as I believe there is a safer and more efficient way w/ Entity Framework. Will keep you posted on what I discover.

Comment: Please do. Thank you!